# Signing code with certificate in Azure Key Vault Managed HSM

Tags: azure, code-signing, hardware-security-module

I am trying to sign code with a certificate from Azure Key Vault Managed HSM. This is an EV certificate, so I cannot just use a normal Azure Key Vault as in the helpful walkthrugh here does:
https://seankilleen.com/2020/05/how-to-use-azuresigntool-to-sign-files-with-azure-devops-using-a-certificate-in-azure-keyvault/

I keep getting the error:
"Failed to retrieve certificate codesign from Azure Key Vault. Please verify the name of the certificate and the permissions to the certificate. Error message: Not Found"

It is not a requirement that I use azuresigntool - are other tools available?
I think I have checked all the permissions, but I cannot see the "Access policies" for an HSM key vault. Instead, there is an RBAC setting - here, I have granted my application the Managed HSM Crypto User role for all keys.
But still no luck.

Comment: I just work on the periphery of these technologies. My observations are: 1. I don't see anywhere that indicates an EV certificate is technically different to any other certificate; 2. That article is three years old. Typically you no longer use Access Policies to grant access. Instead use RBAC. I hope this helps

Comment: Found my error - I had stupidly generated keys instead of certificates...

Answer (score 2):

It was my own fault: I had added keys to the key vault, not certificates.